# I want to draw an ellipse on top of my button, form application C#

Tags: c#, forms

I have some problems with drawing a circle/ellipse on top of my buttons since i draw them onto the form and not the button itself meaning they end up getting covered by the buttons.

right now I draw the ellipse like this

```
   Pen green = new Pen(Color.Green, 1);
   Rectangle rectEllipse = new Rectangle(100, 40, 30, 30);
   e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(black, rectEllipse);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to draw on `Button`, not on `Form`:

```
private void myButton_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  //DONE: wrap IDisposable into using 
  using (Pen green = new Pen(Color.Green, 1)) {
    Rectangle rectEllipse = new Rectangle(10, 10, 30, 30);
    // typo? You, probably, mean "green", not "black"
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(green, rectEllipse); 
  }
}
```

Comment: i have 2 pens actually, i just copied the wrong line of code

Comment: also how do I connect the function to my buttons?

Comment: @c7nt: you have to assign `Paint` events of the buttons you want to paint on